# How to validate the JSON message in a POST request with Beego

Tags: json, go, beego

I'm using Beego to develop a web server.

I used `beego.Controller` to process the POST requests. In my case, the POST request contains a JSON:

```
{
    "name": "titi",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
type TestController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

type User struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

func (c *TestController) Post() {
    var ob md.User
    var err error
    if err = json.Unmarshal(c.Ctx.Input.RequestBody, &ob); err == nil {
        logs.Debug(ob.Name)
        logs.Debug(len(ob.Name))
    } else {
        logs.Error("illegal JSON")
    }
}
```

This piece of code works fine. With the help of tags of the struct `User`, `"name"` is assigned to `ob.Name` and `"password"` is assigned to `ob.Password`.

Now, I want to test some exception cases. For example, what if the JSON request doesn't contain the keys as expected:

```
{
    "illegalKey1": "titi",
    "illegalKey2": "123456"
}
```

As you see, I'm expecting `"name"` and `"password"` but now the keys become `"illegalKey1"` and `"illegalKey2"`. So I'm thinking this can cause some errors.

To my surprise, there isn't any error because `err == nil` is still true, and `len(ob.Name)` just becomes 0 now.

So is there some good method to process this case in Go/Beego?

I mean, I know that

```
if len(ob.Name) == 0 {
    logs.Error("illegal JSON")
}
```

is OK but I'm wondering if there is some kind of more beautiful code? Otherwise, if there are 10 fields in the JSON, I have to do such an `if` 10 times. Obviously this is not good at all.

Comment: See if this https://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/params.md#retrieving-data-from-request-body is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that JSON does not contain unexpected fields you can use `Decoder` from `"encoding/json"` package and it's method [DisallowUnknownFields](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields). See example here https://play.golang.org/p/bif833qxytE

Note that to `json.NewDecoder` takes `io.Reader` as an input. You can create `io.Reader` from `[]byte` by using [bytes.NewReader](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader)

Another topic is making sure that JSON contains all fields that are expected (OR these fields are in certain format). The answer to how make it work with `"encoding/json"` package is to implement custom `UnmarshalJSON` for the struct, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39134081/10461720). But I would not suggest using this approach for such task, because basically this is a validation of an input and I would rather use validation packages for this not to mix responsibilities. The most common one is [go-playground/validator.v9](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9) where you should look for `required` tag. Validation cases are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955036/idiomatic-way-to-validate-structs-in-go/).

Comment: `DisallowUnknownFields` is helpful but it can't detect if a field of JSON missed.

Comment: So if I'm expecting two fields: `"name"` and `"password"`, but the JSON containing only `"name"` won't cause any error. Meaning that I get an object of `User` with the empty `Password`.