# Golang validator multifield dependency

Tags: validation, go, struct

I'd like to validate the following structure :

> ```
> type CarModel struct {
>   gorm.Model
>   OwnerID    int    `json:"ownerid" validate:"nonzero"`
>   Type       string `json:"type" validate:"regexp=(?)(A|B)"`
>   A        string `json:"url" validate:"isurl"`
>   B         string `json:"ip" validate:"isip"`
> }
> ```

I would like to validate A and B depending on Type, 
if type = A then A must exist and must be a URL BUT B must not exist
if type = B then A must not exist and B must be an IP

is this possible with validator ?

I did try custom validation but I cannot find a way to see type value :

```
func checkB(v interface{}, param string) error {
    theB := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if theB.Kind() != reflect.String {
        return validator.ErrUnsupported
    }
    //check if B is an IP
    ipcool := net.ParseIP(theB.String())
    if ipcool == nil {
        return errors.New("B : ip incorrecte " + theB.String())
    }
    return nil
}
```

---

Upon the answer of Alex Nichol, I would like first to thank you for your help.

If I understood correctly, I would have to iterate through all the "validate" fields, to keep a trace of the value of TYPE, A and B and then to check them depending on TYPE ...

I did this :

```
func checkMonitor(v interface{}) error {
    var mytype string
    var myA string
    var myB string

    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    // Iterate through fields
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        // Lookup the validate tag
        field := val.Type().Field(i)
        tags := field.Tag
        _, ok := tags.Lookup("validate")
        if !ok {
            // No validate tag.
            continue
        }

        // Get the value of the field.
        fieldValue := val.Field(i)

        switch field.Name {
        case "Type":
            mytype = fieldValue.Interface()
        case "A":
            myA = fieldValue.Interface()
        case "B":
            myB = fieldValue.Interface()
        }
        // Validation logic here.
        //fmt.Println("field", field.Name, "has validate tag", validate, "and value", fieldValue.Interface())
    }
    if mytype == "A" {
        if myA == "" {
            return errors.New("A vide et type A")
        }
        ipcool := net.ParseIP(myA)
        if ipcool == nil {
            return errors.New("A incorrecte " + myA)
        }
    } else if mytype == "HTML" {
        if myB == "" {
            return errors.New("B vide et type B")
        }
        _, urlpascool := url.ParseRequestURI(myB)
        if urlpascool != nil {
            return errors.New("B incorrecte " + myB)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

but got an error on the mytype, myA and myB in the switch case :

cannot use fieldValue.Interface() (type interface {}) as type string in assignment: need type assertion

EDIT : 
just needed to use my brain :

```
switch field.Name {
case "Type":
   mytype = fieldValue.String()
case "A":
   myA = fieldValue.String()
case "B":
   myB = fieldValue.Interface()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use reflection to iterate over the fields of the struct, get the `validate` tag for each field, and check the field. This means you'll have to do validation on a struct level. Otherwise, if you pass something like `myInstance.OwnerID` to a function, you'll lose the tag associated with it.

This code loops through the fields of a struct and gets the `validate` tag for each:

```
func checkStruct(v interface{}) error {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)

    // Iterate through fields
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        // Lookup the validate tag
        field := val.Type().Field(i)
        tags := field.Tag
        validate, ok := tags.Lookup("validate")
        if !ok {
            // No validate tag.
            continue
        }

        // Get the value of the field.
        fieldValue := val.Field(i)

        // Validation logic here.
        fmt.Println("field", field.Name, "has validate tag", validate, "and value",
            fieldValue.Interface())
    }
    return nil
}
```

For example, we could pass it the following `CarModel`:

```
checkStruct(CarModel{
    OwnerID: 2,
    Type:    "B",
    A:       "http://google.com",
    B:       "192.168.1.1",
})
```

and it would print out the following:

```
field OwnerID has validate tag nonzero and value 2
field Type has validate tag regexp=(?)(A|B) and value B
field A has validate tag isurl and value http://google.com
field B has validate tag isip and value 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your validation rules are very complicated, but you can give [validating](https://github.com/RussellLuo/validating) a try.

Suppose we already have two customized validators `IsURL` and `IsIP`, then your validation rules can be implemented as follows:

```golang
import (
    "regexp"

    v "github.com/RussellLuo/validating"
)

// Customized validators
var (
    MatchRegexp = func(pattern string) v.Validator {
        return v.FromFunc(func(field v.Field) v.Errors {
            switch t := field.ValuePtr.(type) {
            case *string:
                if matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(pattern, *t); !matched {
                    return v.NewErrors(field.Name, v.ErrInvalid, "does not match")
                }
                return nil
            default:
                return v.NewErrors(field.Name, v.ErrUnsupported, "is unsupported")
            }
        })
    }
    // IsURL and IsIP are omitted
)

type CarModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    OwnerID    int    `json:"ownerid"`
    Type       string `json:"type"`
    A          string `json:"url"`
    B          string `json:"ip"`
}

func main() {
    car := CarModel{}
    errs := v.Validate(v.Schema{
        v.F("ownerid", &car.OwnerID): v.Nonzero(),
        v.F("type", &car.Type):       MatchRegexp("(A|B)"),
        v.F("a", &car.A): v.Lazy(func() v.Validator {
            if car.Type == "A" {
                return v.All(v.Nonzero(), IsURL())
            }
            return v.Not(v.Nonzero())
        }),
        v.F("b", &car.B): v.Lazy(func() v.Validator {
            if car.Type == "B" {
                return v.All(v.Nonzero(), IsIP())
            }
            return v.Not(v.Nonzero())
        }),
    })
}
```